# Python List sorting, sorting dictionaries within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to basically have a sorted list of my list of dictionaries that looks like:

```
similarity = [{'Ben': 49}, {'Moose': 18}, {'Reuven': 39}, {'Cust1': 58}, {'Cust2': 10}, {'Francois': 58}, {'Jim C': 39}, {'Iren': 13}, {'Cust3': 13}]
```

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a list of single-entry dictionaries? Could these be merged into a single dictionary?

Comment: @senderle: Or maybe he could just use a list of tuples...

Answer (score 4):

You should be using a list of tuples here:

```
>>> lst = [d.items()[0] for d in similarity]
>>> lst
[('Ben', 49), ('Moose', 18), ('Reuven', 39), ('Cust1', 58), ('Cust2', 10), ('Francois', 58), ('Jim C', 39), ('Iren', 13), ('Cust3', 13)]
```

Then you can sort those as usual.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(1))
[('Cust2', 10), ('Iren', 13), ('Cust3', 13), ('Moose', 18), ('Reuven', 39), ('Jim C', 39), ('Ben', 49), ('Cust1', 58), ('Francois', 58)]
```

If you want, you can also use a single, [ordered dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to hold the values:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(1)))
OrderedDict([('Cust2', 10), ('Iren', 13), ('Cust3', 13), ('Moose', 18), ('Reuven', 39), ('Jim C', 39), ('Ben', 49), ('Cust1', 58), ('Francois', 58)])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it.

```
>>> sorted(similarity, key=lambda x: x.values()[0])
[{'Cust2': 10}, {'Iren': 13}, {'Cust3': 13}, {'Moose': 18}, {'Reuven': 39}, {'Jim C': 39}, {'Ben': 49}, {'Cust1': 58}, {'Francois': 58}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I face difficulty in this.
So I suggest you do in this method

```
a = {'Ben': 49}
b =  {'Moose': 18}
ab = {**a, **b}
print(ab)
{'Ben': 49, 'Moose': 18}

1: sorted(ab.values())
[('Ben', 49), ('Moose', 18)]

2: sorted(ab.items())
[18, 49]
```